# Неправильно определяются приоритеты таблиц стилей

Tags: html, css

В простейшем тестовом коде по факту приоритет имеет связанная (внешняя) таблица стилей (по отношению к глобальной таблице):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Зеленый цвет текста</title>
    <style>
        p {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="color.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Текст абзаца зеленый
</p>
</body>
</html>

Файл css имеет вид:  

p {
    color: green;
}
```

В итоге цвет фразы ТЕКСТ АБЗАЦА ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ будет зеленым. То есть связанная таблица стилей будет иметь
больший приоритет. Хотя в учебниках четко говорится о более высоком приоритете глобальных таблиц над
связанными.
Если поменять элементы style и link местами, то цвет фразы меняется на красный. Получается, что приоритет
этих элементов все-таки зависит от взаимного положения?! Но это противоречит не только информации в
учебниках, но и в видео: в https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEDUcQ1tsHs автор говорит о том, что взаимное
положение этих элементов не влияет на приоритет (3:55 хроно).
На всякий случай ссылки на мой тестовый код:

https://github.com/znoserg/External_style_win
[https://github.com/znoserg/Embedded_style_win.git](http://github.com/znoserg/Embedded_style_win.git)

Чудеса! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, я читал про приоритетность тех значений свойств, которые стоят ниже. Но как я понял, это относится к определению приоритета внутри конкретной таблицы стилей (а не между таблицами разных типов) или же для нескольких таблиц одного типа (например, если несколько связанных таблиц). Иначе почему пишут про приоритет глобальной таблицы над связанной, если приоритет определяется взаимным положением элементов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

почему неправильно? стили накладываются один на другой. т.е. свойство описанное в файле стоит под свойством описанном в самом документе. применяется то свойство которое описано ниже. каскадность. а вот место где оно описано совершенно не важно. к примеру вы можете описать стили в теге, и они будут иметь максимальный приоритет не потому что они в теге, а потому что стили в теге ниже всех.

P.S. единственное, что в CSS нужно понимать, какое свойство описано последним (сверху вниз), то и будет применено.

Посмотрел видео. Он ошибся. Либо он про другую версию CSS говорит)) Ему бы на уроках помогло использование настоящего браузера и кода, вместо записанных слайдов.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что в сети куча ресурсов, где объясняется точно также. Возможно, что переписывают друг у друга. Может в CSS что-то поменяли. Надо позже разобраться будет...

Comment: ну я последний раз css читал 8 лет назад. и ничего из того что я знал не поменялось)

Comment: Согласен, что многие ресурсы переписывают друг у друга и ошибка может кочевать по источникам. Но я смотрел и в относительно новых книгах. На стр. 467 Р. Никсон "Создаем динамические веб-сайты ..." 2020 г (англоязычный оригинал вышел в 2018 г) есть нужный абзац: "... сначала обрабатываются все внешние таблицы стилей и к документу применяются их стили. Затем обрабатываются любые встроенные стили (которые находятся внутри тегов <style>...</style>. Все, что конфликтует с внешними правилами, получает приоритет и заменяет эти правила.

Comment: В книге Макфарланда "Новая большая книга CSS" 2016 г. нашел инфу, которая подтверждает правильность ответа. Цитата со стр. 128: "если имеются конфликтующие стили (или
их свойства) во внешней и внутренней таблицах стилей. В этом случае важна по-
следовательность размещения на веб-странице (в HTML-коде файла). Если вы
сначала добавляете внутреннюю таблицу, используя элемент style,
а затем присоединяете внешнюю таблицу с помощью элемента link, то будет при-
менен стиль последней (в сущности, это принцип, который только что был описан:
значение имеет последний из конфликтующих стилей).